# Cannot open apps script project after switching to legacy editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I recently had to switch to the legacy editor to get my script to be able to be tested as an add-on. However, now that I've done this, I can't open my project. I see this:
Error page[image]

I also made it a Google Cloud project at one point, could that cause a problem?
Why is this happening? How can I open my project again?

Comment: You might be able to get into it through the developers hub. You can also use the app script API to get the code and move it to another file.

Comment: Are you logged into multiple Google accounts?  If so, log out of all accounts, and log back into just the account that is the owner of the file.  Also, close your browser, and reopen it.  I doubt that associating the Apps Script project with a Cloud Platform Project is the problem.  You can right click the file in Drive and choose "download" and it will convert the file to a JSON file and download it to your computer drive.  I'd like to know if that works.